# Data Standardization in DBSCAN Clustering

Tags: clustering, standardization, dbscan

"If the data has a much different range of measurement values, data standardization is carried out so that the distance calculation becomes effective. For example, if the income variable is annual income in dollars and the age attribute is a person's age in years, then income will have a much higher influence."

I'm still confused. For example, the data on the number of infectious disease cases has the same unit in each variable, namely cases. However, it has a different range of values such as:

- X1: 5-1000
- X2: 700-20000
- X3: 0-200
- X4: 0-5

Is it necessary to standardize the data first before doing DBSCAN analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is necessary to normalize the data before applying DBSCAN. This is because DBSCAN uses a simple distance function for it's algorithm. If you don't normalize, the distances are typically determined only by the difference in the column with the largest numbers. But you typically want all columns to contribute more or less equally to the algorithm.

In your case, X2 is the column with large differences, and X4 is small.

If you have three observations,

A: X2=7090, X4=0
B: X2=7100, X4=1
C: X2=7100, X4=5

Then intuitively, on X2 these observations are almost the same (if they come from a range of 700-20000) but on X4, the difference between B and C is quite large. Still, C is much closer to B (distance `sqrt(16) = 4`), than C is to A (distance `sqrt(101) ~ 10`.